# .html() returns empty string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the code:

```
        htmlObject = '<div status-box></div>';
        template = $compile(htmlObject)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
        console.log(template);
        var templateAsHtml = template.html();
        console.log(templateAsHtml);
```

and the output:
from the first console.log:

> `{0: <div status-box="" class="ng-scope"></div>, length: 1}`

and from the second:

> `''`

It seems like the moment I call .html it just not converting it and it is empty.

Comment: `var templateAsHtml = template[0].outerHTML;`, why?

Comment: html() gets innerHtml so you have to use outer one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you ask for `.html()` of an element you will get the `innerHTML` of it. Since `'<div status-box></div>'` has no child nodes the behavior is correct. If you want to return the HTML including the object itself you need to use `outerHTML` function.

```
var templateAsHtml = template[0].outerHTML;
console.log(templateAsHtml);
```

See docs:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Note: the `[0]` is used to access the vanilla JavaScript object inside of your wrapper object.